# What is the dimension of this linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> We are in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and we have the vectors $a_{1}=
> \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, a_{2}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 
> 0\\  1 \end{pmatrix}$ and the linear subspace $U = \left\{
> \begin{pmatrix} x\\  y\\  z \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x-3y+z =0
> \right\}$
>
> What's the dimension of the linear subspace $\text{span} \left\{
> a_{1},a_{2} \right \}+U$?

$\text{span} \left\{
a_{1},a_{2} \right \}+U = s\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & x\\ 
1 & 0 & y\\ 
0 & 1 & z
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
s\\ 
t\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

Now I tried to calculate the rank of the $3 \times 3$ matrix by using Gauss:

Take first line and subtract it with second line:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & x\\ 
0 & 1 & x-y\\ 
0 & 1 & z
\end{pmatrix}$

Now take second line and subtract it with third line:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & x\\ 
0 & 1 & x-y\\ 
0 & 0 & x-y-z
\end{pmatrix}$

We see that the rank is $3$ because we didn't get any full zero line, thus the dimension must be $3$.

---

Please can you tell me if I did it correctly and if not, how is it done easily and correctly? I need to know for my exam, would be very very nice of you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are correct that elements of $\text{span}(a_1, a_2) + U$ are linear combinations of elements of both spaces, you were wrong in assuming that elements of $U$ are vectors $(x,y,z)$, since you did not take into account that the elements of $U$ satisfy $x -3y + z = 0$.

So how would we solve this question? Well, you already have two vector spanning $\text{span}(a_1, a_2)$, namely $a_1, a_2$ (this you did correct!). Now let us find vectors which span $U$. Since we are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you might see that $U$ is a plane, hence two dimensional. Note that two vectors spanning $U$ are $(1,0, -1)$ and $(3, 1, 0)$ (you might find other vectors, but in order to keep things as easy as possible, choose vectors with as many zeros as possible!). Now we apply what you have done: we put the four vectors in a matrix and use Gaussian elimination to find (possible) zerorows. We have the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
and after Gaussian Elimination, we find:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
so we find that the rank is 3, hence the dimension is 3 (as you concluded, but not in a correct way).

$\textbf{EDIT 1}$: I have made a terrible mistake: $(1,0,0)$ is NOT an element of $U$, I will edit it! This will change the resulting Gaussian Elimination, but (afther I have checked it) not the result about the dimension!

$\textbf{EDIT 2}$: in case you were wondering how we could see that the dimension of $U$ is 2: note that we have that the elements in $U$ satisfy $x - 3y + z = 0$. If you do not know that this represents a plane (through the origin) in $\mathbb{R}^3$, note that we have that 
$$x + z = 3y$$
and equivalently 
$$\frac{x + z}{3} = y.$$
Hence the elements in $U$ are of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
\frac{x+z}{3}\\
z
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore, we only have two variables. Taking $x = 3, z = 0$ results in $(3, 1, 0)$ (Note that I could have taken $x = 1$, and this would result in the second coordinate being $\frac{1}{3}$, but I do not like fractions in my matrix and scaling a vector does not change anything). Taking $x = 0, z = 3$, we find $(0, 1, 3)$. This are not the vectors I have taken before, but it shows (in my opinion) better that $U$ has dimension 2. This implies that you can pick any two linearly independent vectors as a basis of $U$ (making my choice valid).

$\textbf{EDIT 3}$ (content of my comment on this answer): If you are not used to the notion of 'rank', we could also argue as follows: Clearly $a_1, a_2$ are linearly independent, so the span a space of dimension 2. Since $U$ is also of dimension 2, we have two possibilities: either $U$ is a part of $\text{span}(a_1, a_2)$, in which case the total dimension is 2, or $U$ is not a part of $\text{span}(a_1, a_2)$. You can show that the second case must hold by finding a vector $u$ in $U$ (such as the ones I already described) and show that $a_1, a_2, u$ forms a triple of linearly independent vectors.

Comment: Damn so this is not as easy as I expected, currently reading your answer and trying to understand. But one thing needs to be cleared as I need it almost everywhere :o  Rank = dimension, right? Also for matrices of other sizes, not just $3 \times 3$. And please don't be strict with that question as maths usually is. I just want know if I know the rank I can say, well the rank is as example 3, so the dimension is 3 as well.

Comment: yes, determining the rank gives you the dimension of the space. Anyway, if you have not seen this (yet), you could also argue as follows: clearly $a_1, a_2$ are linearly independent. This is a two dimensional space. Therefore we have that the dimension of $\text{span}(a_1, a_2) + U$ is either 2 (if $U$ is a part of $\text{span}(a_1, a_2)$) or 3 (if this is not the case). So if you can find a basis vector of $U$ which is linearly independent of $a_1, a_2$, then you are done. However, this amounts almost to the same work as I did, but it is a possible alternative, so I wanted to let you know.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded this different: A basis for an $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists out of $n$ vectors $a_i = (a_{1i}, a_{2i}, \ldots, a_{ni})$, where $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$. So what I meant with a basis vector $u$ of $U$ is a vector $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$, where $u_1, u_2, u_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ (and in the case of $U$ satisfying $u_1 - 3u_2 + u_3 = 0$).